# Scraping href, teams, odds off bet site

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data off of this [website](https://www.bluebet.com.au/sports/Soccer/100).  The page uses heavy javascript and I am struggling to get the href and odds off it.

My current output looks like this:

I am wanting my output to look similar to... (in green):
[image]

[image]

```
class BlueBet(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "BlueBet"
    start_urls = ['https://www.bluebet.com.au/api/sports/SportsMasterCategory?withLevelledMarkets=true&id=100']

    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 'odds.csv',
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)

        for master_category in data['MasterCategories']:
            for category in master_category['Categories']:
                for event in category['MasterEvents']:
                    item = {}
                    item['Event_name'] = event.get('MasterEventName')
                    item['Outcomes'] = {}
                    try:
                        for market in event['Markets']:
                            item['Outcomes'][market.get('OutcomeName')] = market.get('Price')
                    except TypeError:
                        continue
                    yield item
```

Comment: If the site is populating the values using Javascript, then I guess your best bet (no pun intended) is to use Selenium.

Comment: @HavanAgrawal It seems to scrape okay actually.  view-source:https://www.bluebet.com.au/sports/Soccer/100 .  I'm just struggling to get the right elements

Comment: If you track the calls the website makes to render the data on the page you might notice this call: https://www.bluebet.com.au/api/sports/SportsMasterCategory?withLevelledMarkets=true&id=100. All you need to do is parse the returned json.

Comment: Instead of `except TypeError: continue` use `except TypeError as e: print(e) ; continue` and you will see when and why you get error. It should helps you to see if you get correct element from JSON, or maybe it needs to get element form another list or dictionary. You can also use `print()` to see what you have in your variables. It also should help you to see if you get correct item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get data like this

```
{
    'Event_name': 'Melbourne Victory v Adelaide United', 
    'Outcomes': {
        'Melbourne Victory': 2.05, 
        'Draw': 3.5, 
        'Adelaide United': 3.4
     }
}
```

and you want to split `Outcomes` into separated columns.

But columns need names in scrapy `Item`.
I will use names `key1`, `val1`,  `key2`, `val2`, `key3`, `val3`

```
data = {'Event_name': 'Melbourne Victory v Adelaide United', 
  'Outcomes': {'Melbourne Victory': 2.05, 'Draw': 3.5, 'Adelaide United': 3.4}}

# ---

item = {'Event_name': data['Event_name']}

for number, (key, val) in enumerate(data['Outcomes'].items(), 1):
    number = str(number)
    print(number, key, val)
    item["key"+number] = key
    item["val"+number] = val

print(item)
```

and this gives item

```
{
    'Event_name': 'Melbourne Victory v Adelaide United', 
    'key1': 'Melbourne Victory', 
    'val1': 2.05, 
    'key2': 'Draw', 
    'val2': 3.5, 
    'key3': 'Adelaide United', 
    'val3': 3.4
}
```

And this should gives you data in separated columns in Excel.